# Unity3D Player Error "Receiving unhandled NULL exception Obtained 22 stack frames."

Tags: unity-game-engine, error-handling

I have developed a Unity3d Mac standalone app, which crashed after a while with the  above mentioned error - the whole app gets frozen.

I have pages with a video, which I load and un-load dynamically when entering/exit the page. Most of the time the app crashed when I leave the page with the video to the menu. Anyone any idea, I did find anything valuable answer to this matter :(

----- Tests -----
After a few test runs, I narrowed it down to the video. Not sure what exactly the issue is, but when I played a video and leave the page the app freezes...sometimes immediately, sometimes after a while.

Unity 2018.1f
Tested on : Mac OSX 10.12.6 & OSX 10.11.6

Answer (score 0):

After long tests and try-outs, we found a general problem with Unity and continues playing videos. After updating everything, as well as to the latest Unity2018.2 version - it finally was working well. As per Unity changelog, they did some fixes on the VideoPlayer.

Good luck.